# how much will $\$10,000$ grow to in three years at the same rate of interest?

Tags: finance

> If $\$64$ grows to $\$128$ in four years at a constant effective annual interest rate, how much will $\$10,000$ grow to in three years at the same rate of interest?

I tried to use $(1+i/n)^{n-1}$ to solve for the interest rate but I don't understand how to use the numbers $64$ and $128$...

I know the answer is $\$16,817.93$

thanks in advance

Comment: I first thought you missed a `$` in the title :P

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume interest rate $i$, where $i=0.1$ means $i = 10\%$

Now, if you start with amount $x$, then after 1 year you get as interest $i*x$, which means that after one year you have $x + i*x = (1 + i) * x$

After the second year, you earn interest over that amount, so you get $i*(1+i)*x$ interest. Hence, after two years you have amount $(1+i) * x + i * (1 + i) * x = (1 + i) * (1 + i) * x = (1 + i) ^ 2 * x$

You can now hopefully see that this pattern repeats: after $n$ years, you will have amount $(1 + i)^n*x$

So, in your case, since you start with $x = 64$, and since after 4 years you are at 128, you need to solve for:  $64*(1 + i)^4 = 128$, i.e. for: $(1 + i)^4=2$ to find interest rate $i$. So: $ 1 + i = 2^{\frac{1}{4}}$

So, $i =  2^{\frac{1}{4}} - 1 \approx 0.189$ or about $18.9%$ (hmm, sounds like a typical credit card ...)

Anyway, when you start with $x= 10,000$, after three years you will have $10,000*(1+i)^3$. So, here you can fill in $i$ ... or you can you the earlier finding that $ 1 + i = 2^{\frac{1}{4}}$, and hence $(1+i)^3 = 2^{\frac{3}{4}}$. Either way, you get $10,000*(1+i)^3 \approx 16,818$

Comment: why dont isnt the interest rate divided by the number of years? where does this equation come from

Comment: General compound growth formula for principal $P$, interest rate $r$, times compounded $m$ times, $n$ years later is $P \, \left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^{m \, n}$.  Here $P=64$, $r=i$, $m=1$, $n=4$.

Comment: to clarify, we are to assume this is a compound interest rate and not a simple rate from the phrase "(constant) effective interest rate" right? Since EIR by definition $i = \frac{A(n)-A(n-1)}{A(n-1)}$ it follows that $A(n) = A(0) \cdot (1+i)^n$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $128 = 2\cdot 64$. So, the amount of money doubles every $4$ years, giving us
$$P(t) = P_0 2^{t/4}$$
Where $P(t)$ is the amount of money at time $t$ years. In this question, $P_0 =10000$, and so $$P(3) = 10000\cdot 2^{3/4} \approx 16818$$